# Multiple Pairs of peers video calling with their respective pair partner on the same domain using webrtc

Tags: webrtc

I have developed a simple webapp of video calling using WebRTC Api.
The app is hosted at **https://54.161.109.227** .

Problem is at a time, only single pair of browsers can make a video call. As soon as third person opens this *webapp* and click on video call button, the video calling session which is already going on between the previous pair of browsers get discontinued.

I want that on the same URL, multiple pair of browsers make video call with each other without disturbing any other pair.

Comment: This is a question about application logic, not WebRTC. All you have is a demo that pairs the first two people who access the server. How you want to discover and connect people beyond that is entirely up to you. Most people use some concept like "rooms".

Comment: Thanks @jib I will look into the concept of "rooms".

Comment: Finally the concept of rooms solved my problem. Thanks @jib for your suggestion.